# Rotating and translating camera in 3D space

Tags: 3d, c++11

I'm having a slight problem translating and rotating my camera in 3D space. In Direct3D9 a camera is defined as position, looking at, and up axis (as 3d vectors). So I stored the camera's rotation and position, and when defining the camera for a new frame, I rotated the looking at vector and up axis by the rotation and set the position. When translating the camera, I took the translation, rotated it by the rotation and translated the camera's position and looking-at vector by that. But after some time the looking-at vector and the new translation don't line up - that is, the camera no longer moves forwards when the translation vector is a straight multiple of the original looking-at vector which defines forwards. I can't understand why this occurs- any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could you be experiencing [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)?  This has occurred to me before and so I dumped vectors and moved to [Quaternions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206327%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't think so. The D3DX function to create the view matrix only takes D3DXVECTOR3s. I can't work with Quaternions.

Comment: @DeadMG, you can multiply a D3DXVECTOR3 by a D3DXQUATERNION, if that *is* the issue.  It definitely sounds similar.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Then why isn't the LookAt vector having the same gimbal lock as the translation vector? I also didn't find any functions to multiply a D3DXVECTOR3 by a D3DXQUATERNION- and checked the operator overload too.

Comment: I solved the problem by computing a new LookAt vector every time, rather than caching it and trying to update it with the correct translation. This definitely solved the problem at hand.

Comment: @DeadMG, glad that solved it.  The function isn't actually in the DirectX SDK (AFAIK).  I can edit my answer to show it if you want it for future reference?

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Not particularly :P Doing my best to hack this bit together and move on.